# WYGWAM in comments form

Tags: wygwam, comments

I need to use WYGWAM in comment form.
Now I use {exp:comment:form} as it is shown in EE documentation.
But it is necessary for me that users could format the text with power of WYGWAM! How can I embed it to comment form?

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible with any of the wysiswyg editors for EE. Have you considered making a feature request?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I will try to make this request.

Answer (score 0):

My current project requested this, and after trying to build out a custom solution, I came across SCEditor, a jQuery plugin that's worked perfectly. It's lightweight and easy to customize (both the JS and the CSS).

Link: http://www.sceditor.com/